# Need to center images in wyswyg block

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg

I am trying to center 3 images in a block I have created in my footer but
the images just won't center. I tried the wysiwyg editor's center button, but that did not work. I then tried to put in manual css which failed. I can't seem to get these images to center. I would appreciate any help.

Using: 
    CKEditor    7.x-1.13

I tried adding a Bootstrap 3 "center-block" css class, but this does not work either.

```
<p>© 2014 Environmental Law Alliance Worldwide (ELAW)<br />
U.S. Office: 1877 Garden Avenue, Eugene, OR 97403 USA<br />
Phone: +1 541 687 8454<br />
Fax: +1 541 687 0535</p>


    <div class="center-block">
    <a href="/projects/edigest/user"><img class="float-left img-responsive" src="http://localhost/projects/edigest/sites/all/themes/bootstrap-business/images/facebook.png" /></a> <a href="/projects/edigest/manage-translate"><img class="float-left img-responsive" src="http://localhost/projects/edigest/sites/all/themes/bootstrap-business/images/blog.png" /></a> <a href="/projects/edigest/translate"><img class="float-left img-responsive" src="http://localhost/projects/edigest/sites/all/themes/bootstrap-business/images/twitter.png" /></a>
    </div>
```

Here is what displays:
[image]

Comment: What Text Format are you using in the textarea ie Full HTML, Filtered HTML?
Can you inspect the element in your browser to see what html and css is being output by Drupal?

Comment: This is an CSS issue. Look here for inspiration: [Can't center 3 adjacent photos using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654811/cant-center-3-adjacent-photos-using-css) and [CSS - center two images in css side by side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819417/css-center-two-images-in-css-side-by-side)

Answer (score 0):

Add the "center-block" class to the **img** tag.